# Using Java server-side with PHP-generated front-end

Tags: java, php, ajax, dwr

Does anyone have a real-world experience in building such a project? I'd like to move away questions about "is it good idea or not", but focus on possible solutions. I see one simple way - HTTP GET/POST + xml/json - and one more elegant - AJAX/DWR. As for the first one - I understand that it is possible, but needs quite a lot coding. As for second way - is it possible to use Java DWR engine with PHP front-end? Is DWR language-independent for client side (as it uses just JavaScript)?
 
 Would it be a problem, that client page was generated by one web server (for example, apache+php) and served on server-side by another (for example, tomcat)? I suspect, that Tomcat will complain about sessions. Can this problem be fixed with allowing cross-domain AJAX?
Thank you in advance.
Denis.

Comment: php-generated HTML pages at front-end, of cause :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to do is (as I suspect) to use PHP to assemble your web pages while the "business logic" is written in Java, I would suggest using [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/index.php) (LGPL and MIT licenses)

Comment: +1 - Nice link! This might be exactly what the OP is looking for, especially if he is trying to leverage an existing Java code base.

Comment: Interesting link. Have anyone ever used it in real life?

Answer (score 2):

Both Java and PHP are server-side technologies. Your "front-end" will be written using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript - although you could certainly use PHP (or JSP) templates to render portions of the front-end.

If you are using PHP as the "front-end", then you would need it to act as a proxy, passing requests back to the Java web server.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the question. "PHP front-end" means "front-end HTML pages, generated with PHP". As for a acting like proxy - cannot agree. You can implement simple REST web services in Java and call them from PHP-generated HTML page (with JS of cause). Do not see any proxy here. Do you?

Comment: My point is that if the Java web server is on a different "domain" then you cannot call its services directly. You will need to call back to the PHP server, which will act as a "proxy" to then query the Java web service.

Comment: @Storm - I still don't see the point of trying to mix two server-side technologies. What would you gain? When it comes to web content PHP and JSP can offer more or less the same functionality. You can just pick one.

Comment: @Manos - Agreed, although if the OP already has a lot of Java code he is trying to leverage, I suppose I could see the value in using something such as the PHP/Java Bridge. Otherwise there is no good reason to use two different server-side technologies.

Comment: @Manos - As I mentioned in the question, I'd like to skip the discussion about "is it good idea or not". Thank you.

Comment: @Justin - "you cannot call its services directly". There is such a thing like "cross domain AJAX". Wouldn't it help in this situation?

Comment: Absolutely. See: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/cross_domain_aj -  In the past I have used the "proxy" approach, although you might consider a different one.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on a project that uses a Java 'backend' and a mod_perl 'frontend'. For the naysayers, this is because the Java is providing service/API facilities, it's not and shouldn't be involved in dealing with UI, be they HTML, WAP, SMTP, SOAP, etc.

For historical reasons the mod_perl talks XML-RPC. It's not a route I'd recommend at this stage. Java, Perl and PHP can quite happily handle far more JSON type transactions due to lower encoding/decoding overhead. Also, in a mod_perl (though not PHP) environment it's possible to run JSON-RPC easily over a persistent connection, reducing the overhead even further.

There are plenty of benefits to this approach, including separate upgrades to the various UIs, stability of the service layer, and distinct responsibilities for each layer.

Downsides include delays getting service improvements live, more complicated development, staging and test environments, a taller barrier to entry for new developers, more documentation and management.

For the "Java front to back" guys, this is a similar type approach to using an OSGi container, only using more domain suitable languages; Java for heavy lifting, scripts for more fluid, text based interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for understanding the problem! :) For now it seems to me that some simple REST service + XML/JSON would be the easiest way.